# Using Tor proxy with scrapy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, tor

I need help setting up Tor in Ubuntu and to use it within scrapy framework.

I did some research and found out this guide:

```
class RetryChangeProxyMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        log.msg('Changing proxy')
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet('127.0.0.1', 9051)
        tn.read_until("Escape character is '^]'.", 2)
        tn.write('AUTHENTICATE "267765"\r\n')
        tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
        tn.write("signal NEWNYM\r\n")
        tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
        tn.write("quit\r\n")
        tn.close()
        time.sleep(3)
        log.msg('Proxy changed')
        return RetryMiddleware._retry(self, request, reason, spider)
```

then use it in settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE = {
                         'spider.middlewares.RetryChangeProxyMiddleware': 600,
                         }
```

and then you just want to send requests through local tor proxy (polipo) which could be done with:

```
tsocks scrapy crawl spirder
```

does anyone can confirm, that this method works and you get different IPs?

Comment: Just try on your own resource and check server logs. And set list of browser identificators for hiding from owners :) or add unic id for your crawler.

Comment: How do I set a list of browser identifications?

Comment: Oh... I didn't work with scrapy, so I just look in help  now :) . But for tests on you own site better use unic id for easy parsing logs

Comment: [Basic recommended settings](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/settings.py) and here [snippet](http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/27/) for randomising. A [LOT of reading about browser ids](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I found the snippet and integrated it already :)

Comment: http://pkmishra.github.com/technical/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this snippet: http://snipplr.com/view/66992/use-a-random-user-agent-for-each-request/

Update: broken link fixed

Comment: This link seems to be broken.

Comment: Random user agents still can be tracked.