# Changing Tor identity in Scrapy over Polipo

Tags: python, scrapy, tor

I am trying to build a CrawlSpider using Scrapy to crawl sites in Tor.

To do this I am using the Polipo proxy as described by this guide:

http://blog.privatenode.in/torifying-scrapy-project-on-ubuntu/

So right now my spider works and I am able to access .onion sites in Scrapy. However what I would like to do is, for each request, send a NEWNYM signal in order to change my Tor identity.

How can this be done in Scrapy?

Comment: Maybe as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603423/using-tor-proxy-with-scrapy ?

Comment: Using your suggestione I have added the following lines to my code:
`tn = telnetlib.Telnet('127.0.0.1', 9050)
        tn.write("signal NEWNYM\r\n")
        tn.close()`
However I am not too sure it will work. How can I check if my Tor identity is actually changing?

Comment: https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor may give you ideas...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to to play around with my torcc configuration but from the logs I can't really read if the path is changing. Any ideas on how to do that? What should I look for??

Comment: @Simus add a print line in python that prints the current public ip address of the process after you set the signal NEWNYM. That way you know for sure that your connection changed.

Comment: Have you managed to solve your issue?